# ADD_MONTHS in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, oracle, date, database-migration, date-arithmetic

I have issue change `ADD_MONTHS` Oracle to PostgreSQL.

I have Oracle query like this :

```
ADD_MONTHS (to_date(to_char(start_billdate,'DD-MM-YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY'), 
           (processed_num*periodvalue)
           )
```

So how to implement that query to PostgreSQL?

Comment: `to_date(to_char(start_billdate,'DD-MM-YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY')` is pretty much useless in Oracle to begin with. If `start_billdate` is a `date`, then this can be simplified to `start_billdate` or if you are trying to set the time part to midnight: `trunc(start_billdate)`

Answer (score 2):

One option might be to multiply number of months (`processed_num * periodvalue`) with the *interval* of 1 month and add that to `start_billdate`:

```
start_billdate + (interval '1 month' * processed_num * periodvalue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct an interval with the contents of the column:

```
start_billdate + make_interval(months => processed_num*periodvalue)
```